# Search for files by content only in trunk subdirectories

Tags: files, find, search, recursive

I think its a simple question, but the answer is probably a little more complicated :P

**Edit:** Actually, its not complicated at all!^^

So I have a directory with multiple svn projects and I would like to search through all recent files (in trunk folder) by content in all projects.

Here is somewhat the folders look like:

```
Projects
|
->Project1
|   |
|   ->tags
|   |
|   ->trunk
|
->Project2
|   |
|   ->tags
|   |
|   ->trunk
...
```

Comment: `grep -l some-pattern ./Projects/Project*/trunk/*`? Or more specific requirements?

Comment: well the projects aren't really named ProjectX, but I guess ./Projects/*/trunk/* should do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comments above:

```
grep -l some-pattern ./Projects/*/trunk/*
```

or recursively if there are subdirs under each `trunk` (and your `grep` supports `-r`):

```
grep -lr some-pattern ./Projects/*/trunk/
```

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks for the edit. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) does indeed not specify a recursive option for grep. Also noted BSD grep man page says `-r` is deprecated in favour of `-R`. GNU and BSD grep support `-R` - are there still modern systems with a non-recursive grep?

Comment: Note that BSD grep (except recent OpenBSD) is now a fork of an old version of GNU grep. With recent GNU grep, `-r` should be preferred over `-R` as it doesn't follow symlinks (BSD greps handle the symlink issues differently/better). The `grep` of most commercial Unices don't support `-r`.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name .svn -prune -o -path '*/trunk/*' -type f -exec grep pattern {} +
```

Comment: `-exec **grep** pattern`, no?

Comment: @grebneke, oops, yes sorry. Fixed.

Comment: This works, but I think the solution in the comment is more generic. The svn vas just an example, but I'll probably need this for other dirs too :) + the output is colored, which is awsome! :P